# How do I get the buried bean to the right of the volcano?

Tags: mario-luigi-dream-team

In *Mario & Luigi: Dream Team* how do I get to the buried bean to the right of the volcano on Mount Pajamaja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will eventually **get a new ability** that helps you get to the bean.

Spoilers about which ability:

> The ability you will need is the ball hop, which serves as a higher jump. With it, you can return to the volcano and jump up there.